# generate signed .apk in jenkins with gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, sign

This is part of my jenkins job configuration:
[image]

Build this job, and I get the .apk(s) here:

[image]

As you can see, all the .apk(s) are unsigned.

Now, ***How to sign one/all of these .apk files WITHOUT edit my build.gradle. I want to add a new task after the build, but I don't know where to configure my keystore and the generated apk path***
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahhhhhhh~ finally!! I solve my problem. (LOL....)

Here's the trick:

**1.** Add build step -> Execute shell:

[image]

**2.** edit command lines, format: **jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $KEYSTORE/JKS -storepass $PASSWORD -signedjar $SIGNED.APK $INPUT_UNSIGNED.APK $KEY_ALIAS**
[image]
**3.** Post-build Actions -> add post-build action:

[image]

**4.** edit **app/build/outputs/apk/*-signed.apk**

[image]

After the **Build Now** operation, you will see the target signed apk files:
[image]

Comment: Can you please write proper command withe xample password keystore path alias everything ?

Comment: Did you place signed apk file to the path first ? and then set this path in command ? and "File to archive"

Comment: @AhmadArslan , “$SIGNED.APK ” stands for a target will be generated, "$INPUT_UNSIGNED.APK" is the unsigned apk in my question, such as app/build/outputs/apk/branch-releas-unsigned.apk

Comment: " Execute shell:", is this step before or after gradle build please?

Comment: @AllenXia the gradle build is for generate unsigned apk file, same as in Android Studio, after this "Execute shell" is to sign this .apk file. Can you get that?

Comment: @ChinglimCHAN thanks a lot for the reply. I was newbie to Flutter, but now it's all clear to me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the `(?)` icon next to each field to get help.

The [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-signing) also links to detailed [usage documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-signing-plugin#usage).